# How can I refresh navigation page from left menu master page if navigation page is already on top of the stack?

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, xamarin.forms

So, I have a master page that contains the left menu you access from the hamburger icon on Page A.

On that left menu, I have a button called "Refresh Page A" and when I click that button, I want the contents of Page A which is already on top of the stack to refresh/reload.

However, I'm having an issue because the constructor, onResume and onAppearing do not get called. I'm not sure how to make the left menu button refresh Page A.

In my LeftMenu class, I have something like

```
this.Add(new MenuItem()
{
    Title = "Refresh Page A",
    Icon = "icon.png",
    SelectedIconSource = "icona.png",
    TargetType = typeof(PageA),
    Tcolor = COLOR_MENU,
    SelectedTColor = Color.White,
    MenuType=MenuType.PageAType,
    ToolbarResource = Resource.Layout.mainpage_toolbar
});
```

This is how I am navigating to the page:

```
case MenuType.PageAType:
    Pages.Add(id, new NavigationPage(new PageA ()));
    break;
```

So how do I refresh the page? I have a refresh method I can use but where should it be called from?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

So I see a couple of ways to do this.

1. Keep track of what is shown currently in the Details page by keeping a reference to that page. This way you can detect whether it is of the type you are expecting and call a method instead of trying to push that page again.

So in your switch case detect which page type is going to be shown (you already do that), then if the current page is the same type, don't navigate again, just call the refresh method:

```
case MenuType.PageAType:
    if (_currentPage != null && _currentPage.GetType() == typeof(PageA))
    {
        var page = (PageA)_currentPage;
        page.Refresh();
    }
    else
    {
        _currentPage = new PageA();
        Pages.Add(id, new NavigationPage(_currentPage);
    }
    break;
```

2. Alternatively you can send a Message using the Messaging center in Xamarin.Forms.

In your page that you want to refresh:

```
MessagingCenter.Subscribe<MasterDetailPage>(this, "Refresh", (s) => {
    Refresh();
});
```

This line subscribes to "Refresh" messages from the sender of type `MasterDetailPage`. When that is received it calls the `Refresh` method.

Then in your switch case for navigation:

```
MessagingCenter.Send<MasterDetailPage>(this, "Refresh");
```

This will send a message to all subscribers of this message.

Comment: Thumbs up for the MessagingCenter solution.

Comment: Where should I put the MessagingCenter code? Inside the constructor of my page?

Comment: Yeah you can put the subscription in the ctor. As for the Send, obviously where you want to send the message.